# Recognizing multiple string values in a single action 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Thanks again for the help.

I have a simple action that checks the stringValue of a textField, and if it matches - a status message prints in a second textField:

```
 if 

 (textField.stringValue == (@"Whatever" )){
 [outputDisplay setStringValue:@"Success"];
```

My question is how do I implement multiple input stringValue options in this method? For example "Whatever" "Whatever1, Whatever2" all return "Success" in the outputDisplay.

thanks.

Paul

Answer (score 11):

Create a set of answers you're looking for and test if the string in question is in there.

```
NSSet *successStrings = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Whatever1",
                                              @"Whatever2",
                                              @"Whatever3",
                                              nil];
if ([successStrings containsObject:st]) {
    [outputDisplay setStringValue:@"Success"];
}
```

(An array would also work, but a set is specialized for testing membership, so it's a better fit for what we're doing here.)

Comment: This is good when the set is large and you remember to cache the set. Otherwise the cost to construct the set will overwhelm the cost to test membership.

Comment: This is optimized for readability and ease of updating rather than performance. Neither way should be particularly taxing even on an iPhone. I always prefer less code unless I've profiled and determined that it's creating a performance problem.

Comment: Thank You as well. Very helpful.

Paul

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, to check for equality of `NSString`-s you should use `-isEqualToString:`. `==` compares the pointer values which often returns `NO` even if the two strings' contents are the same.

To check if the text field match multiple strings, you connect them with the `||` (`or`) operator, so you get

```
NSString* st = textField.stringValue;
if ([st isEqualToString:@"Whatever"] || [st isEqualToString:@"Whatever1"] || [st isEqualToString:@"Whatever2"]) {
  [outputDisplay setStringValue:@"Success"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Kenny. Very helpful.

Paul